# Reopen Last Closed Tab on Mac in Safari v15.1 (Monterey)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari

I used to use CMD + Z to reopen a recently closed tab. From what I can tell - this feature has been removed from Safari at some point. Now seemingly the only option is CMD+SHIFT+T which exclusively reopens the last closed window. Is there any way to natively reopen last closed tab in Safari?

Comment: Great answers will come of this. In a nutshell, many actions get queued for undo. This requires a dedicated last window shortcut since you can’t skip past all the other items queued by undo/redo. Why not map the exclusive command to shift+command+Z or option+command+Z?

Comment: As far as I can tell - reopening closed tabs has been entirely removed from the cmd+z queue. Nothing I do can bring this back. I am not sure if this is specific to the latest Safari on Monterey

Comment: You will want to change your browser or if you stick with safari,  or change the shortcuts and/or habits.  I’m not sure there’s another way yet…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a new feature. Cmd/Z is a kind of 'smart' undo [& also universal to all apps & indeed all platforms]
Cmd/Shift/T is a specific command [though it does change between Tab & Window depending on what was last closed.] It's located in the History menu rather than Edit.

To test -
Start to type an answer or comment into this page. Check the Edit menu.
Close this tab, check the menu again.

Undo…
[image] [image]

In other apps it can do even more, it is context-sensitive…

[image] [image]

History Undo…
[image]

[image]

I've checked this back to Safari 11 on El Capitan.

It *is possible* to change these commands in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts but I would advise against it.

Comment: I understand this functionality - and this is what I used to expect when using the command. However, it has now been removed entirely as far as I can tell - hence me making this post. I have just tested to make absolutely sure - directly after closing a tab - the History menu bar only has Reopen Last Closed Window (SHIFT+CMD+T) and the edit menu only has a greyed-out 'Undo (CMD+Z) option.

There is no functional way to reopen a closed tab outside if finding the url in your history.

Comment: Okay upon further inspection I have figured out what happened. However, I still believe this to be a bug. 

macOS seems to get hung on a certain window closing sometimes. Regardless of how many tabs you open in other windows after closing that window - that window is always brought back, with further CMD+shift+T's then reopening that windows closed tabs. 

If I go to the previous window I wanted to reopen closed tabs from, exit it (so that it is the most recently closed window) and hit the shortcut now - it only reopens tabs from window I'm already in, not reopening the last closed window

Comment: That,  as far as I can determine from your description, Is also expected behaviour. I’ll need to have a closer look when I get back to my computer.